# How to divide with each other the two queries with different conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

There is a table in which the managers column and the status column. How to calculate the total status of Fully, the divided total of records with all statuses except N / A for each manager?

I tried to portray in this way, but nothing came of it

First Query

```
SELECT "Manager Name", count("Performance Score") as Perfomance FROM public.hr_dataset  WHERE 
("Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets') GROUP BY "Manager Name"
ORDER BY Perfomance DESC;
```

Second Query

```
SELECT "Manager Name", count("Performance Score") FROM public.hr_dataset 
WHERE ("Performance Score" != 'N/A- too early to review') GROUP BY "Manager Name";
```

Need to recieve two columns with name and values (1 query/2 query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    "Manager Name", 
    COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets') Perfomance_Fully_Meets,
    COUNT(*) Performance_Not_NA,
    AVG( ("Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets')::int) Performance_Ratio
FROM public.hr_dataset  
WHERE "Performance Score" != 'N/A- too early to review' 
GROUP BY "Manager Name"
ORDER BY Perfomance DESC;
```

This works as follows:

- filter on statuses other than `'N/A'` (this actually includes the `'Fully Meets'` status)
- aggregate by manager name
- for each manager, do a conditional count of how many records have status `'Fully Meets'`, rendered in column `Perfomance_Fully_Meets`
- for each manager, count the total of records (`'N/A'` were filtered out already), in column `Performance_Not_NA`
- if you want the ratio of `'Fully Meets'` records, you can do it using `AVG()` on the result of condition `Performance Score" = 'Perfomance_Fully_Meets`'; in numeric context, a true condition evaluates as `1` and false as `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and decision!
But could you please clarify, why 'N/A' were filtered out in column Performance_Not_NA. Are they filtered when we write condition WHERE? So is Performance_Ratio column filtered by the same way?

Comment: @Bimka09: yes. `'N/A'`s are filtered out by the `WHERE` clause ; *then*, the counts are evaluated.

Comment: can you advice, where I can find more information about this construction? AVG( ("Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets')::int)

Comment: @Bimka09: condition `"Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets'` is evaluated in integer context: true is `1`, false is `0`. Averaging this gives your ratio of records that satisfy the condition in the group of records..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, you can use `FILTER` to limit the counted rows according to the performance score.

```
SELECT "Manager Name",
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE "Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets')
       /
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE "Performance Score" <> 'N/A- too early to review')
       FROM public.hr_dataset
       GROUP BY "Manager Name";
```

BTW, you have terrible column names there, with all the spaces and caps and stuff...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm not architector of this DB(
Thank you very much for your decision!)